# Counting items tagged as required and that are missing or partly existing in another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been wrestling around with this query for too long of a time now and can't get it working.

I have a rather simple database structure that includes the following tables: 
(I've left out unnecessary fields)

```
DEVICES
-------
id
identification
type_id     (type of device)


DEVICES_TYPES_DOCUMENT_TYPES
----------------------------
id
device_type_id INT
document_type_id INT
document_required INT(1) (has a value of 0 = not required for this device type OR 1 = required)

DEVICES_DOCUMENTS
-----------------
id
device_id
document_type_id
filename
```

Now, let's say I have 5 devices that have 2 required "document types" attached to their "device type", e.g. "Purchase invoice (document_type_id: 1)" AND "Warranty document (document_type_id: 2)". I have uploaded a total of 3 documents for the 5 devices in the database. I'd need one query (if possible) to return all the devices and the number of missing documents in them using these tables.
In my example I would receive a list of 5 devices in which one of them has "1" as missing documents (device id: 2), one of them has 0 missing documents (device id: 1) AND the rest 3 devices that have no uploaded documents attached to their device type, have "2" as the number of missing documents.
I've built a few queries but with no luck this far.. Any ideas appreciated!
I know I could do this with a little help from PHP but due to a large database it would eventually get slow..

Sample database with data:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `identification` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `devices` (`id`, `type_id`, `identification`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Device 1'),
(2, 1, 'Device 2'),
(3, 1, 'Device 3'),
(4, 1, 'Device 4'),
(5, 1, 'Device 5');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices_documents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'devices.id',
  `document_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'devices_types_document_types.document_type_id',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`,`document_type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `devices_documents` (`id`, `device_id`, `document_type_id`, `filename`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'type_1_for_device_1.pdf'),
(2, 1, 2, 'type_2_for_device_1.pdf'),
(3, 2, 1, 'type_1_for_device_2.pdf');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices_types_document_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'devices.type_id',
  `document_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'devices_documents.document_type_id',
  `document_required` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `device_type_id` (`device_type_id`,`document_type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `devices_types_document_types` (`id`, `device_type_id`, `document_type_id`, `document_required`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 1);

Comment: Could you potentially provide some example data just so we have a better idea as to whats going on? I'm not sure I fully understand what is being asked. (it may just be me though)

Comment: you can use not in or not exists

Comment: I modified the question to meet sample data provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? WARNING: untested

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devices_types_document_types WHERE device_type_id = d.type_id)-(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devices_documents dC, devices_types_document_types dT WHERE dC.device_id = d.id AND dT.device_type_id = d.type_id AND dC.document_type_id = dT.document_type_id AND dT.document_required = 1)) as missing_documents, d.* FROM devices d
```

Comment: Hi, the number of required documents should come from the table "devices_types_document_types" for each device_type_id (devices.type_id)

Comment: Just do another SELECT COUNT(*) for this table instead of just putting "2" there. Was this what you were saying?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the example data you provided. It works fine for me.

Comment: For a second I thought this was it but still one small glitch, I'll try to figure it out myself too but:
If I upload 2 documents that are both the same document type and leave the other required document not uploaded, it says "0 missing", should be "1" missing. Somehow it does not take the document types into account while comparing what's really missing and what's not?

Comment: Got it working :)

Changed "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devices_documents dC" TO "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dC.document_type_id)) FROM devices_documents dC"